# Overriding a props type in child component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using a third party component, and it expects a prop to be a particular type.

I wish to use a different type.

Is there a way to override the type of a child component prop?

Or would I have to use a computed property and modify the prop in the parent component to the type the child component requires?

Comment: I don't think you can override that. Wouldn't that also just break the 3rd party component? I'd go with the second variant either way.

Answer (score 1):

**In general i think the best way would be to do as you proposed**: To "use a computed property and modify the prop in the parent component to the type the child component requires". If you have to do so in several places, you could outsource the logic into a mixin that will be imported whenever the given third-party component is used.

If modifying the type of the property in the parent component isn't an option, the best way to fulfill your needs would be **creating your own component that extends from the third party component and overriding the needed property**. (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends)
Keep in mind however that the dependency containing the third-party might get updated over time. You should probably stick to a fixed version if following this approach.

I created a simple example on how to extend and override components (You can check it out as CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/qq9y7nm8n4

**App.vue:**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h2>ExtendedComponent: </h2>
    <extended-component :message="1" />
    <h2>BaseComponent: </h2>
    <base-component message="This shall be a string" />
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import ExtendedComponent from "./components/ExtendedComponent";
import BaseComponent from "./components/BaseComponent";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    ExtendedComponent,
    BaseComponent
  }
};
</script>
```

**BaseComponent.vue:**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>prop type: {{ typeof message }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "BaseComponent",
  props: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**ExtendedComponent.vue:**

```js
<script>
import BaseComponent from "./BaseComponent";

export default {
  name: "ExtendedComponent",
  extends: BaseComponent,
  props: {
    message: {
      type: Number,
      required: false
    }
  }
};
</script>
```